# Remove BpmnJs symbol

Tags: angular6, bpmn.io

I am trying to use `Bpmn-JS` in my project.

So when I tried to create workflow I saw

[image: green symbol at bottom right]

can anyone tell how to remove that as it was coming dynamically in the canvas..!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**We can't remove Logo as per License**

[BPMN License](https://bpmn.io/license/)

Answer (score 2):

[image]You have to inspect the element on browser & find the path or you can apply CSS to that element as `style="visibility:hidden"`
see below I have made it hidden

Comment: Can u create the stackblitz & share the same

Comment: Error in /turbo_modules/diagram-js@2.5.1/lib/draw/DefaultRenderer.js (23:19)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd decide to not comply with BPMN licence, you'd do something like:

```js
document.querySelector('a[href="http://bpmn.io"]').remove()
```

But you should not.